# No query results for model [App\Facility] getAllData

Tags: ajax, laravel, datatables

i want to ask about this question, because this is make me crazy.

So i want to load datatables using ajax, i got this in view

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "facility/getAllData",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Then this is my routes

```
Route::get('/master_data/facility/getAllData', 'FacilityController@getAllData')->name('facility.getAllData');
```

The last Part is my controller

```
public function getAllData()
{
    $facilities = Facility::all();

    return response()->json($facilities);
}
```

Thats all my code, i already use App\Facility; what is wrong with my code? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a named route so you will need to add something like this to your view:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: {{ route("facility/getAllData") }}, // named route
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

or use the full route url `url: "/master_data/facility/getAllData"`